# Can't use PutHiveQL in NiFi

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, apache-nifi

It gives me the following error :

```
2019-07-21 11:29:58,105 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding PutHiveQL[id=f58fb42e-016b-1000-c1d4-199cdeb7bdb9] due to uncaught Exception: 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.LogDivertAppender.setWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)
```

Comment: can you add processor configuration ?

Comment: @maximeG In HiveConnectionPool : 

Database Connection URL : jdbc:hive2:///[Database_name]
Hive Configuration Resoucres : referencing hive-site.xml, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml